# EF6 MVC5 Why is LINQ trying to update child entities that are not linked virtually?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have just updated our project from MVC4 and EF5 to MVC5 and EF6 using Code-first approach and I came across a potential problem which I do not recall happening in the older version.
When updating a single entity, I received a db error which was complaining a non valid property in a child entity. I the checked the model and this child entity does not have the VIRTUAL property set. So I am wondering why EF would be trying to update the child?

Here is the model that I am updating:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subscriber ID")]
    public int SubscriberId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }

    public List<Website> Websites { get; set; }
}
```

The Websites property is the one I am referring to.

Here is the Action code:

```
Subscriber subscriber = db.Subscribers
                           .Include(s => s.Websites.Select(w => w.DomainNames))
                           .Single(s => s.SubscriberId == FormSubscriberID);

subscriber.InjectFrom(viewModel, subscriber); //sets the values from the viewModel

db.Entry(subscriber).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I don't typically use the include syntax in my queries - I tend to use the the more verbose 'from' syntax. As a test I removed the includes and everything worked fine.

Could using the '.Include' syntax have something to do with the behavior I am seeing or is EF really trying to update the child entities automatically?

Comment: BTW - After removing the included entities from the query, the update works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF will assume all collections/complex types on an entity are navigation properties. Virtual is not required to map a navigation property, it simply allows that navigation property to be lazy loaded.

If you want to exclude a complex type/collection from being turned into a nav property use the `[NotMapped]` attribute or the `.Ignore(t => t.PropertyName)` modelbuilder lambda

Comment: Thanks Luke! That makes sense. Just to confirm, it was the same in EF4?